# clear <select> dropdown in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to clear a  type dropdown list with  children and JQuery Empty() command works for Chrome (and I assume every other browser) but not Internet Explorer.

I have tried this

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").length = 0;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").innerHtml("");
```

but returns

```
document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
```

.

```
   var DropDown = $("#dropdown");
    Dropdown.Length = 0;
```

doesn't seem to have any effect 
(not sure if you can use pure JavaScript methods on JQuery variables?)

Any reliable way to clear a  element in Internet Explorer?

the HTML is messy as it's generated from ASP in SharePoint but here's the relevant output that the browser and javascript reads from

I'm using Jquery 1.11.3 (from google Apis)
and Internet Explorer 11

```
<tr>
        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Interaction Contact</nobr>
    </h3></td>
        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <!-- FieldName="Interaction Contact"
             FieldInternalName="Interaction_x0020_Contact"
             FieldType="SPFieldLookup"
          -->
            <span dir="none"><select name="ctl00$m$g_d04d1ad3_87fc_4751_9c85_4974c40486ca$ctl00$ctl05$ctl07$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$Lookup" id="ctl00_m_g_d04d1ad3_87fc_4751_9c85_4974c40486ca_ctl00_ctl05_ctl07_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup" title="Interaction Contact">
                    <option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option>
                    <option value="15788"> John doe , john-doe@mail.net</option>
                    <option value="15788"> John doe , john-doe@mail.net</option>                    
                <!-- lots of <option> elements that needs to be cleared -->
                </select><br></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: try it  *$("#dropdown").html(" ")* or  *$("#dropdown").empty()*

Comment: @Balachandran returns html is not a function
.innerHtml = " " runs but doesn't clear the list.

Comment: Post your html as well. And what version of IE and jQuery we're talking about?

Comment: Updated the question with that info

Comment: Just to check.. you are using the id `ctl00_m_g_d04d1ad3_87fc_4751_9c85_4974c40486ca_ctl00_ctl05_ctl07_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup` not `dropdown`, right?

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can clear it cross browser with :

```
$("#dropdown").empty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").options.length = 0;
```

To do it with jQuery:

```
$('#dropdown').empty();
```

Comment: both works in Chrome, neither works in Internet Explorer. It returns " Object required" on the first option

Comment: Try with $('#dropdown').html(""). If it works, I will update the question.

Comment: .html() is not a function and .html = ""; runs but doesn't clear the list

Comment: Probably you are not including jQuery as well.